# Python: Web scraping using requests-html not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, python-requests-html

I'm trying to scrape data from a [trading website](https://www.screener.in). I started out with the python 'requests' library, but the HTML page it returned was different compared to the one on my browser.

I observed that the web page had a minor delay in loading the missing information, on researching, I found out that this can be resolved using the 'requests-html' package. But, the 'requests-html' library returns the same HTML as 'requests'.

I am aware that this can be solved by using selenium but is there a way to do this using the above-mentioned libraries?

This is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
from requests_html import HTMLSession

with HTMLSession() as s:
    login_url = 'https://www.screener.in/login/'
    USERNAME = "username"
    PASSWORD = "password"

    s.get(login_url)
    csrftoken = s.cookies['csrftoken']

    login_data = dict(csrfmiddlewaretoken=csrftoken, next='', username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)
    s.post(login_url, data=login_data, headers={"Referer": "https://www.screener.in/"})

    r = s.get('https://www.screener.in/company/ABBOTINDIA/')
    r.html.render(timeout=10, sleep=10)
    print(r.html.html)
```

Where am I going wrong? Is something wrong with the headers?

I am new to web scraping and would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you have to login? If you go to the ur for ABBOTINDA you can still see the stock information. Also, if the response you are getting is different than what you see rendered in the browser, then it is being displayed through JavaScript and you will have to use Selenium.

Comment: @A.Patterson, some financial ratios (other than the basic ones) can be added by the user as per their preference and the user needs to login to access other ratios

Answer (score 0):

`csrftoken` and `csrfmiddlewaretoken` are not the same.

`csrfmiddlewaretoken` needs to be sent via the response data while `csrftoken` needs to be a cookie.

They also have (for me at least) different values.